# Simplify, $\Bigg(\frac{x^2 - 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}{x^2 + 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}\Bigg)$ where $x > 3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Simplify, $$\frac{x^2 - 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}{x^2 + 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}$$ where $x > 3$.

**What I Tried**: I tried to rationalize the denominator by multiplying with $x^2 + 4x + 3 - (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9})$ to get :-
$$\Bigg(\frac{x^2 - 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}{x^2 + 4x + 3 + (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}} * \frac{x^2 + 4x + 3 - (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}{x^2 + 4x + 3 - (x - 1)\sqrt{(x^2 - 9)}}\Bigg)$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{2(x - 1)(x^2 + 4x\sqrt{x^2 - 9}x - 9)}{(x^2 + 4x + 3)^2 - (x - 1)^2(x + 3)(x - 3)}$$

I was only able to get to this, and I am stuck on how to move next. Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: The answer that is given in my side is $\sqrt{\frac{x^2 - 9}{x + 3}}$ , so for now none of the answers match with it.

Comment: The denominator simplifies to $(x+3)(10x^2-6)$

Comment: You could write the fraction as $1-{8x\over x^2+4x+3+(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-9}}$ first and then do the multiplication. After that you can probably cancel out the $\sqrt{x+3}$ on the top with the $x+3$ in the bottom but that's pretty much it.

Comment: I don't think so @cr001. cf my answer (for your first comment)

Comment: @math $(x^2+4x+3)^2$ is not $(x-1)^2(x-3)^2$ in the first step. It's $(x+1)^2(x+3)^2$.

Comment: Also, the answer that is given is $\sqrt{\frac{(x^2 - 9)}{x + 3}}$ , in that case none of the answers match with it.

Comment: @Anonymous The answer is wrong. If you sub in $x=5$ you get $3\over 8$ for the original expression but $\sqrt{2}$ for the "answer".

Comment: I think Tarvish's answer is correct. My first comment should be $(x+3)(10x^2+6)$ and then everything matches his answer.

Comment: @Anonymous The [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lqm8mfvy9h) are different for the question and the answer provided in your book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{(x-3)(x-1) +(x-1)\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}{(x+3)(x+1) +(x-1)\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}\\ 
= \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}} \frac{\sqrt{x-3} +\sqrt{x+3}}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+3}+(x-1)\sqrt{x-3}}$$

Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x-3}$.

$$=  \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}}\frac{6}{8x-2\sqrt{x^2-9}} \\ =  3\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}} \frac{4x+\sqrt{x^2-9}}{15x^2+9} \\ =  \frac{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x+3} \frac{4x+\sqrt{x^2-9}}{5x^2+3} \\ =\frac{(x-1)(x^2-9 +4x\sqrt{x^2-9})}{(5x^2+3)(x+3) } \\ =\frac{(x-1)(x-3)}{5x^2+3} +\frac{4x(x-1)}{(5x^2+3)(x+3)} \sqrt{x^2-9}$$

I doubt this can be simplified any further.

Comment: Check my edit, it does not match with your answer. Maybe some other approach can simplify more, or else I can assume the answer given is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2+4x+3)^2 - (x-1)^2(x+3)(x-3) = (x+1)^2(x+3)^2 - (x-1)^2(x+3)(x-3) = (x+3)(10x^2 + 6)$

And $x^2 + 4x^2\sqrt{x^2-9} -9 = \sqrt{x^2-9}(\sqrt{x^2-9}+4x^2)$.

So you get $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}(\sqrt{x^2-9}+4x^2)}{(x+3)(10x^2 + 6)} = \frac{\sqrt{x-3}(\sqrt{x^2-9}+4x^2)}{\sqrt{x+3}(10x^2 + 6)}$$

Or $$\frac{(x-3)(x+3)+4x^2\sqrt{x^2-9}}{(x+3)(10x^2 + 6)}  = \frac{x-3}{10x^2+6} + \frac{4x^2\sqrt{x^2-9}}{(x+3)(10x^2 + 6)}$$

Comment: Is this the answer? Also how did you come up with this idea, I would have taken at least 45 mins.

Comment: no but I simplified your denominator and factorized the numerator. Actually when you have a polynomial of degree $2$ $(ax^2 + bx + c)$ it's often useful to look if it has a trivial root (generally look if $0,1,-1$ are roots) That's how I did it.

Comment: And I think you can't get much simpler than the numerator / the denominator I gave you.

Comment: Check my edit, it does not match with your answer. Maybe some other approach can simplify more, or else I can assume the answer given is wrong.